# C#. How to correct log Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Any to JSON

Tags: json, .net, asp.net-core, logging, protocol-buffers

I have a problem to log readable requests/responses WellKnownTypes.Any in message via `Interceptor` using gRPC.

I added LoggingInterceptor to my rpc clients. It uses `System.Text` to log any messages and write to ELK/console, some code below.

```
private static readonly JsonSerializerOptions DefaultOptionsToLog = new JsonSerializerOptions()
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
    Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping,
    IgnoreNullValues = true,
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
};
public static string ToJsonLog<TValue>(this TValue value, JsonSerializerOptions options = null) => JsonSerializer.Serialize<TValue>(value, options ?? JsonExtensions.DefaultOptionsToLog);


private async Task<TResponse> InterceptCall<TRequest, TResponse>(
    TRequest request,
    Grpc.Core.AsyncUnaryCall<TResponse> continuation,
    string methodName)
{
    TResponse response1;
    try
    {
        string jsonLog1 = request.ToJsonLog<TRequest>();
        this._logger.LogInformation("GRPC CLIENT REQUEST:\r\nMethod: " + methodName + "\r\n" + jsonLog1);
        TResponse response2 = await continuation;
        string jsonLog2 = response2.ToJsonLog<TResponse>();
        this._logger.LogInformation("GRPC CLIENT RESPONSE:\r\nMethod: " + methodName + "\r\n" + jsonLog2);
        response1 = response2;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this._logger.LogError(ex, "GRPC CLIENT EXCEPTION:\r\nMethod: " + methodName + "\r\n" + ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
    return response1;
}
```

Everything works correctly with normal types and messages. But if message has `WellKnownTypes.Any` type (I'm trying to use this as Generic in C#), then I see a serialized bytes of information in the log messages, not a JSON representation.

Example of message log:

> GRPC CLIENT REQUEST: Method: /CardDeactivation.ScreenService/GetScreenInfoForOperation {"screenType":2,"screenParams":{"typeUrl":"type.googleapis.com/CardDeactivation.CardCloseParams","value":[10,108,10,21,208,151,208,190,208,187,208,190,209 e.t.c...]}}

My messages:

```
message ScreenInfoRequest {
ScreenType screen_type = 1;
google.protobuf.Any screen_params = 2;
}

message CardCloseParams {
CardInfo card_to_close = 1;
repeated CardInfo cards_to_choose = 2;
repeated AccountInfo accounts_to_choose = 3;
bool is_last = 4;
}
```

**I would like to register "screenParams" as a normal non-serialized default object property (e.g. "screen type":2)** How i can do this?
Maybe use `Unpack` before log, but I can't find a universal solution for this in `async Task<TResponse> InterceptCall<TRequest, TResponse>()` method.

I tried to use various serialization options, expected to get readable text in messages, but received an array of bytes of information. I also tried to decode from the decimal number system, UTF-8 and e.t.c., looked for a solution in the documentation, but I didn't find it.

- https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/proto3/#any
- https://protobuf.dev/reference/csharp/api-docs/class/google/protobuf/well-known-types/any

Expected results = see a readable representation of objects in the logs, not an array of bytes

Comment: It's unclear from your question whether you understand the role of WKT [Any](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/proto3/#any). An Any represents a(n embedded) serialized (!) protobuf message (and a reference to this message's type). In your example, the bytes are the message and the type is `"type.googleapis.com/CardDeactivation.CardCloseParam` (corresponding to the default naming of a package `CardDeactivation` and a message `CardCloseParam`). You'll need to be able to access the referenced type (either by a Descriptor, stubs or Proto)  in order to correctly decode it.

Comment: Although unlikely (!), it's possible (!?) that the embedded message contains further embedded messages.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But I was asking if there is some mechanism to auto decrypt WLT `Any` and log it. At the moment, there is only one idea - Add a switch for `"typeUrl":"type.googleapis.com/CardDeactivation.CardCloseParams"` and deserialize it to the necessary type

Comment: Сan you tell me how to manually get the text with an array of bytes? 
What types of encoding and in what sequence should I use?

This is not a solution to the problem, but this way I can at least decipher the log

Comment: Encoded protobuf messages **aren't** self describing. The `Any` field `value` contains an encoded message and the only (practical) way to decode it is by `switch`'ing on the `type_url` field to access a copy of the relevant schema's (a) stubs; or (b) descriptor. Good luck!